# Duda al crear archivo desde un bat

Tags: batch, msdos, .bat

Desde mi archivo bat necesito comprobar si un archivo existe, si es true , agregarle la data
mi ejemplo

```
if exist E:\back\pasados\%1 (
   type %1 >>E:\back\pasados\%1
   del  %1
) else (
   move %1 %backup%
)
```

El problema es la linea :  type %1 >>E:\back\pasados%1

Necesito que agregue un salto de linea al inicio, porque la primera linea que hace el append la situa "inline" con la ultima linea que ya existia ...
Alguien que pueda ayudarme con este batch ?

Answer (score 0):

no obtuve ayuda alguna ... pero para quien le sirva la publico

echo.>>C:\DESARROLLO\Back%1
type %1 >>C:\DESARROLLO\Back%1

Answer (score 0):

No tiene que probar si el archivo existe.  El pipe >> crea el archivo si no existe.  Simplemente `type %1 >>E:\back\pasados\%1` funciona bien.

Comment: gracias, pero justamente necesito saber si existe , la unica duda era como forzar un cambiuo de linea al inicio ...